# Get list names in linked data view on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am quite new to SharePoint and am having a little trouble.  Basically, I have several lists on my SharePoint site each detailing change requests for different applications.

I want to make a data view that inks all of the lists together so that all change requests can be seen at once.  This part works, however I want to also have a column on this data view which shows the name of the list each item came from. e.g.

```
List name: App1
change req 1
change req 2

List Name:App2
change req 1
change req 2

Linked Data View should show
change req 1 - App1
change req 2 - App1
change req 1 - App2
change req 2 - App2
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use three XsltListViewWebPart on the same page. Each web part will show data from separate list. Their headers will contains names of the lists.
2. You can use DataViewWebPart with AggregatedDataSource. Set parameter SeparateRoot to True. Then customize XSL to generate table with formatting you need.